# Percentage of land cover within buffers from NLCD data in R

Tags: r, land-cover, nlcd

I have a dataset that contains geographical coordinates and their unique location names. I need to create a buffer around each and calculate the percent of land cover (derived from nlcd 2019 conus land cover data) within each buffer.

I am trying to run the process with R, however,  final output doesn't contain land cover type names, I have NAs in the top row. This is what I use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearthhires)
library(sf)
setwd('....//covariate_extraction')

install.packages("rnaturalearth")
library(rnaturalearth)
#################  FOR PA ################################


state = ne_states(iso_a2 = "US", returnclass = "sf") %>%  # pull admin. bounds for US
  filter(iso_3166_2 == "US-PA") %>%                      # select Pennsylvania
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs") # nlcd crs


# load the csv file containing longitude and latitude data
data <- read.csv("card_xy_zone17.csv")


# create a new spatial points data frame from the longitude and latitude data
coordinates <- data.frame(data$longitude, data$latitude)
colnames(coordinates) <- c("longitude", "latitude")
spatial_points <- st_as_sf(coordinates, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

# filter the state polygon and transform the spatial points to match its CRS
state <- ne_states(iso_a2 = "US", returnclass = "sf") %>%  
  filter(iso_3166_2 == "US-PA") %>%                      
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
spatial_points_transformed <- st_transform(spatial_points, st_crs(state))
# extract points inside the state polygon
pts <- st_intersection(spatial_points_transformed, state)

# plot the points and state polygon
#plot(pts, col = "red", pch = 20)
#plot(state, add = TRUE)
#plot(sf_object, zcol = "attr2")
#plot(state, zcol = "attribute_name")




# Plot!
#plot(st_transform(pts, 4326), col = "red", pch = 20)
#maps::map("state", add = TRUE)

library(FedData)
install.packages("rgeos")
library(rgeos)

nlcd = get_nlcd(        # fn for pulling NLCD data
  template = state,     # polygon template for download
  label = "4pland",     # this is just a character string label
  year = 2019,          # specify the year (2016 should be available soon)
  force.redo = F
) 
names(nlcd)

unique(nlcd$NLCD.Land.Cover.Class)


# Plot!
#plot(nlcd)
#plot(pts, col="black", pch=20, cex=1.5, add=T)

# Define buffer distance
buffer_dist <- 500  # meters



library(terra)
library(sp)

nlcd.idx <- rast(nlcd)   # create a raster of the same size to hold the buffer index values
nlcd.idx[] <- 1:ncell(nlcd)  # set index values to 1,2,3,... for each cell in the raster
sp.buff <- gBuffer(as(pts, 'Spatial'), width=500, quadsegs=50, byid=TRUE)

buff.sf <- st_as_sf(sp.buff, IDs = 1:length(sp.buff))


ex.mat <- terra::extract(nlcd, sp.buff, df = TRUE)
library(tidyr)


prop.lc <- ex.mat %>%
  setNames(c("ID", "lc_type")) %>%
  group_by(ID, lc_type) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pland = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, lc_type, pland) %>%
  complete(ID, nesting(lc_type), fill = list(pland = 0)) %>%
  spread(lc_type, pland)



nlcd_cover_df <- data.frame(ID = 0:(length(nlcd@data@values)-1), 
                            NLCD.2019.Land.Cover.Class = nlcd@data@names) %>%
  subset(NLCD.2019.Land.Cover.Class != "") %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, NLCD.2019.Land.Cover.Class)

lc.col.nms <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(colnames(prop.lc)[-1]))

matcher <- merge(x = lc.col.nms,
                 y = nlcd_cover_df,
                 by = "ID",
                 all.x = TRUE)

colnames(prop.lc)[-1] <- as.character(matcher$NLCD.2019.Land.Cover.Class)

print(prop.lc)


write.csv(prop.lc, "prop_landscape_500.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This has been addressed numerous times, which would have been reviled by a quick search. The linked answer uses terra, not raster. This is because raster is being depreciated with terra as the replacement. For reading data in terra use the `rast` function rather than `raster` or `stack` as in raster. When working with vector data you must also coerce to the terra vector class using `vect` which can be done within another function. This will directly coerce sf class objects.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the codes and they seem to do a job, except for the fact that in the final output, I don't get names of different classes, instead, I have NAs in the top row